# Rake db:create fails to connect to server

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, rake

I am having some troubles creating my database.

My postgresql is running for sure.

Here's the database.yml:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: name_of_database
  User: username
  Password: tototo
```

I get the message:

```
Called from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
  Is the server running locally and accepting
  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
[...]
/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"name_of_database", "User"=>"username", "Password"=>"tototo"}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
  Is the server running locally and accepting
  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[...]
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"name_of_database"}
```

I created the user giving it every rights.

I can connect to postgresql with the client using the IDs.
And I have an other project succeeding to connect to postgres.

Does someone have an idea to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Post your compose file

Answer (score 1):

Your postgres server might not had started try this

```
$sudo service postgresql restart
```

Then go to your rails project

```
$rake db:setup
$rake db:seed
$rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I said I can connect to it with the psql client. So it does mean the postgresql server is running.

Comment: @YoannPicquenot did you manage to solve this problem?? I'm running into the same problem now